# MS Office/Outlook Presence Integration C# COM Server

Tags: c#, com, outlook, ms-office, office-interop

I tried to follow the instructions found in the article [Integrating IM applications with Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900715.aspx) and implemented the IUCOfficeIntegration Interface in my C# Application and want it to work with Outlook 2010. 
I created an C# Exe that registers the class for COM Interop by basing my code on the official Example [How to develop an out-of-process COM component by using Visual C++, Visual C#, or Visual Basic .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/kb/977996)

When I run the C# COM Server I am able to instantiate the registered class from another C# Application using the following code:

```
 Guid clsid = new Guid("394376DD-3BB8-4804-8CCC-9559434004F3");
 Type t = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(clsid, true);
 object i = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

When the COM Server does not run I get the Error `HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)` as expected.

I enabled Outlook Presence Logging, started the C# COM Server set up the registry keys but Outlook is not able to instantiate my COM Class even though the C# Test app can do it.

In the Outlook Log I get the error line:

`hr = 80040154, We couldn't identify the provider type we now try to manually CoCreate using the LCClient CLSID`

I checked the registry keys but they are correct. For some yet unknown reason it does not work. The docs say Outlook would use CoCreateInstance with the CLSID to instantiate the class.
Does anyone have an Idea what might be wrong. Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: GUID format? C# uses `{xxxxxxxx-xx...}` and `VBA` uses `xxxxxx...`